# How to call a API declared function in frontend flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, flutter-test

[signup(User_Register user has been given in this api call response... Now I have to call this in frontend flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jv2g.png)

[Second picture shows ontap function call for the signup... Now signup(user) how to declare that, is my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yWlP.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do not post code or error text as pictures. See the following link for guidance to write a better question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.